# terminating std::out_of_range while inputing a sentence

Tags: c++, string, loops, output, c++14

This code is about turning strings into a substituting ciper(substituting a specific letter to another specific letter e.g. : 'E' for 'a') When I am inputing a string it works fine. But when I am inputing a sentence it says' Mterminating called after throwing an instant of 'std::out_of_range' ' .What is hapeening? What should I do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    string alphabet {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"};
    string key {"EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz5678"};
    string secret_massage {};
    string encrypted_massage {} ;
        
    cout << "Enter your secret massege : ";
    getline(cin, secret_massage) ;
    cout << "Encrypting massage . . . " << endl;
    cout << "Encrypted massege : " ;
    
    for ( size_t i {0} ; i < secret_massage.length() ; ++i ){
        char selection {};
        int j {};
        selection = secret_massage[i];
        j = alphabet.find(selection);
        encrypted_massage = key.at(j);
        cout << encrypted_massage;
    } [enter image description here][1]
    
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you input a sentence, there is whitespace in the sentence. But `alphabet` does not have a space character ( ). So when `selection` is  , and you do:

```
j = alphabet.find(selection);
encrypted_massage = key.at(j);
```

the result in `j` will be `std::string::npos`, and then using that value in `.at()` will throw a `std::out_of_range` exception.

You can fix this by adding a space to the cipher, or by not doing the substitution when you find a space in the input.